# 6502 Extra Cycles on Page Cross

Tags: clock, memory, cpu, assembly, instruction-set

On the 6502 processor, when using the `Absolute,X`, `Absolute,Y` or `(Indirect),Y` addressing modes, some instructions may require an extra clock cycle if a memory page is crossed.

Such instructions are:

```
ADC AND CMP EOR LDA LDY ORA SBC
```

As an example, the following `ADC` will take 4 cycles:

```
LDX #$10
ADC #$1000
```

While this one will take 5 cycles, because of the page cross:

```
LDX #$01
ADC #$10FF
```

Some other instructions may also encounter a page cross, with the same addressing modes, but do not require an extra clock cycle:

```
ASL DEC INC LSR ROL ROR STA
```

Is there a specific reason for these instructions not to require an extra cycle on a page cross?
Are they implemented in a different way as the others?

Comment: this may be of interest to you ... https://wokwi.com/projects/361208550356234241

Comment: See also: [Why don't all Absolute,X instructions take an extra cycle to cross page boundaries?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/15623); [Why does 6502 indexed LDA take an extra cycle at page boundaries?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/145)